# How to load jQuery UI from Google CDN with locale different than English?

Tags: jquery-ui, localization, internationalization

I would like load a different than English language locale for jQuery UI, while loading jQuery UI from [Google Hosted Libraries CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)?

Is there a way to pass I18n parameter into load function?

```js
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2")
```

I have also tried as per jQuery UI documentation on [Datepicker internationalization](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to pass:

```js
$(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['pl']);
```

... but it did not do the trick :(

Comment: This question does not need to be CW. What parts of jQueryUI do you need localized other than the datepicker?

Comment: Let's start with datepicker, I'm not sure that there is anything else that can be localized. What the guidelines using CW?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

EDIT:

It work's only `google.load` is omitted and standard JavaScript loading is used:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd advise to use
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/**1**/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
as it will always fetch the newest 1.* version (1.7.2 is already really old)

Comment: sorry for faux formatting 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Comment: @Raveren That is a bad idea for two reasons.  First, jQuery changes enough between minor versions that you really need to test.  Second, Google only sets the far-future etags, expires headers and such if you specify the exact version.  You are not getting the advantage of the CDN if you do not specify version X.X.X

Comment: I there a way to specify to only load a specific language ?

Comment: It works only until jQueryUi ver 1.7.3.
Any idea what happened to it after that?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this may not be the answer you are looking for, but I stumbled upon your question when solving the very same problem. 
I am approaching this by loading the i18n libraries from the local server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- local resource -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
```

this code then works:

```
$(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['pl']);
```

I am still interested in how to load the jquery-ui-i18n.js from a CDN.

Comment: Even better you can get it from:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/i18n/ui.datepicker-pl.js